# SwiftUI: How to persist state through different views?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a JSON file of "Countries" and there is a field `isFavorite` which is a boolean value of `false` in the JSON.

I have in my `ContentView`, a list of countries and when you click on the heart beside  them, it does the following:

```
if country.favorite {
    Image(systemName: "heart.fill").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
        countries[index].isFavorite.toggle()
    }
} else {
    Image(systemName: "heart").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
        countries[index].isFavorite.toggle()
    }
}
```

this is fine and works while in this view.  When I move over to `FavoritesView`, all the countries `isFavorite` values are lost and set to the default `false` which was in the JSON.  I keep getting the view to show 'No Favorites!'.  How do I retain the altered state between views?

Below is some of my code:

**MainView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State var countries: [Country] = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
      
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView(countries: $countries)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            MapView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Map", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            FavoritesView(countries: $countries)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Favorites", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
        }
    }
}


func hasFavorites() -> [Country] {
    var favorites: [Country] = []
    
    countries.forEach { country in
        if country.isFavorite == true {
            favorites.append(country)
        }
    }
    
    return favorites 
}
```

**FavoritesView**

```
struct FavoritesView: View {
    @Binding var countries: [Country]
    
    var body: some View {
        if hasFavorites().count > 1 {
            Text("test test: User has Favorites!")
        } else {
            Text("no favorites!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your `hasFavorites` function exists outside of your views. In fact, it's unclear from the code you've included how it's accessing `countries`, since, again, it is outside of the views.

I'd refactor it to be *inside* the view where you need it. I'd also make it a computed property and use `filter` to find only the countries where `isFavorite` is `true` rather than doing the manual loop/append that you're doing right now.

```
struct FavoritesView: View {
    @Binding var countries: [Country]
    
    var favorites : [Country] {
        return countries.filter { $0.isFavorite }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if favorites.count > 1 {
            Text("test test: User has Favorites!")
        } else {
            Text("no favorites!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks for taking the time to explain it as well!